# Laravel forces redirect to public folder when user is not logged in

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I added this rule into the `.htaccess` to redirect all the requests to the public folder:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,NC]
```

This way I can strip the `public` word from the URI, although both `mydomain.com/home` and `mydomain.com/public/home` would work.

I now implemented the basic user authentication but what happens is that:

1. if user requests for `mydomain.com/admin` and is **not** logged in, Laravel redirects him or her to `mydomain.com/public/login` instead of `mydomain.com/login`
2. when user authenticates himself or herself, Laravel redirects him or her to `mydomain.com/public/admin` instead of `mydomain.com/admin`

Based on this, I guess that Laravel, somewhere, explicitates that redirects must be made at `/public/whatever`. I tried to figure out where `redirect()` helper is explicitated but I couldn't find it. My questions are:

- Is my assumption right?
- If *yes*, where Laravel defines that the redirects must be made at `/public/whatever`? Where I can find `redirect()` helper?
- If *no*, why point 1 and 2 occur?

Comment: "_This way I can strip the public word from the URI_" You have `public` in your URIs? `public` should be the document root of your server, never seen the public folder pop up in my Laravel projects

Comment: @kerbholz I always thought I couldn't set `public` folder as document root on my shared hosting; I finally tried after your comment and it's actually not only possible but also even too easy. Thanks

Comment: Np, glad it works

Answer (score 1):

from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#pretty-urls)

**Apache**

> The framework ships with a public/.htaccess file that is used to allow
>   URLs without  index.php. If you use Apache to serve your Laravel
>   application, be sure to enable the  mod_rewrite module.

If the .htaccess file that ships with Laravel does not work with your Apache installation, try this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

If your web host doesn't allow the FollowSymlinks option, try replacing it with  Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch.

Comment: I didn't get it, probably because I don't know `FollowSymLinks` so well. What should be the difference of having `Options +FollowSymLinks` in the `public/.htaccess` and not having it?